# Can't login, although password is correct

Tags: login, password, users

Here what's happening when I try to log in.

I'm entering the right password

[image: login screen]

[image: users at login screen]

It brings me back me to the login screen.

I tried to change password via another user but it didn't help.

Comment: If you have no space in your $HOME (/home/user/ directory), there will be no space for required working-files used by the gui, and login cannot proceed so you are returned to the login dialog.   As Kulfy suggested I'd suggest switching to terminal (ctrl+alt+f4) and login, it'll prove your credentials are fine, and then you can `df -hl` to see if you have enough disk space free to enable gui to work; if not you can find some files to delete, increasing space allowing gui login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've been starting graphic applications from the terminal using `sudo`, that's what probably caused your problem. Always use `sudo -H`.

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type:

  - `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` # remount the disk as rw
  - `cd /home/your_username` # change directory
  - `ls -al .*thority*` # list some files

You should see something like this...

```
-rw------- 1 your_username your_username 407910 Nov  2 08:56 .ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 your_username your_username     58 Jun 23  2017 .Xauthority
```

If it DOES NOT show `-rw-------` then...

- `sudo chmod 600 .*thority*` # change file protection

If it DOES SHOW `root root` then...

- `sudo chown your_username:your_username .*thority*` # change file ownership
- `reboot` # reboot the computer

Reboot and see if you can log in.

Comment: didn't solve the identical problem in my case (ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: @jeremy_rutman Please start a new question.