# Can't login, although password is correct (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: kubuntu, login, kde

Recently my machine started to boot using a login screen featuring a laser-eyed bobcat (possibly a panther.)
[image]
and the laser-puma doesn't accept my login (`failed to start session` , not a wrong password msg).  I do crtl-alt-F3 then login from cli, then run `startx` which gets me to a kde desktop that's pretty nice (the previous default was gnome).  I'd like to 1. be able to login from the getgo, and 2. have kde as the default desktop (tho I care less about this). I've checked all the answers for a similar question (which occurred in [previous versions of ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096011/cant-login-although-password-is-correct)) none of which seem to solve the issue. Some system info (obtained in a terminal window after the sequence described above) :

```
jeremy@jeremy-Blade:~$ uname -a 
Linux jeremy-Blade 5.4.0-70-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 19 13:29:52 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
jeremy@jeremy-Blade:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
jeremy@jeremy-Blade:~$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
KDE
jeremy@jeremy-Blade:~$ ls -l .X*
-rw------- 1 jeremy jeremy 163 бер 23 17:37 .Xauthority
```

Comment: What does this mean? Recently my machine decided to boot using kubuntu it did it all by itself?

Comment: "my machine started to boot using a login screen featuring a laser-eyed bobcat" - You mean the Ubuntu 20.04 wallpaper (it's a foca actually).You've tagged `kubuntu` in this question. Does that mean you had a `KDE` environment installed, with different graphics? Might it been that you or someone else upgraded your OS or changed its environment, thus causing your password to reset?

Comment: I see you've edited your question: it seems that you somehow installed another desktop manager on-top of your `KDE`.

Comment: All that's been done recently are a few `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` commands; I blv I treid out kde a while back but it was never default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropping into non-gui mode (alt-ctrl-F3) then running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` , then choosing a default graphics manager of lightdm took care of it.

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm` and rebooting gets me into kde without problems and actually doesnt need to be run from  non-gui mode.

Actually kde/sddm isn't problem-free, videos in firefox and elsewhere don't run (`if playback doesnt begin shortly try restarting your device` ) so I'm back to lightdm.

Answer (score 0):

I faced to similar issue when I was messing with global PATH variable.

Users with this problem can try checking global env file:

```bash
cat /etc/environment
```

What you should have in PATH at least should like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

In my case I accidentaly overwrote PATH variable instead of adding path to PATH like below, which, apparently broke dekstop GUI:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
PATH="/usr/local/go/bin"
```